# Aplicación multilenguaje, seleccionar entre varios idiomas y quede traducido etiquetas y mensajes MessageBox.Show

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación de Windows Forms y deseo que a partir de una lista desplegable una vez se inicie la aplicación se pueda elegir el idioma, por defecto quiero que el idioma sea en español, al seleccionar el nuevo lenguaje **cambie todos los mensajes y los labels al nuevo lenguaje**, igual que me muestre una imagen del idioma y cuando cambie el idioma seleccionado muestre la imagen de la bandera del país del idioma, si selecciono inglés me muestre una pequeña bandera de Estados Unidos a lado derecho de la palabra Inglés,se que esas configuraciones se deben de hacer en archivos Resources.resx, pero no tengo claro como referencio cada uno de mis controles y el cambio de idioma, por ejemplo, tengo los siguientes controles:
lblNombre
lblFecha
lblDireccion
lblTelefono
lblDescripcion

Con sus respectivos **textos que deben cambiar al idioma que se selecciona**, igual que si selecciona el idioma inglés debe salir antes de que se selecione la fecha en inglés ya que lo guardo es la fecha en formato dd/MM/aaaa.

Donde aparece Nombre debe ser **Name**
              Fecha por **Date**,

Igual que cambie el idioma en los encabezados del gridview.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama *"Localización"*, puedes leer un poco sobre el tema en [Internacionalización y Localización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internacionalizaci%C3%B3n_y_localizaci%C3%B3n). Visual Studio te permite *localizar* una aplicación en C#. Solo debes establecer a `true` la propiedad de cada ventana que desees *localizar*. Esto va a generar el archivo `.resx` correspondiente (1 para el idioma por defecto y otro para el idioma foráneo). Lo que debes hacer es editar dicho archivo y comenzar a traducir las etiquetas de tus elementos y el texto de los mismos.

Comment: Puedes pasarte por [aqui](https://csharpaid.com/windows-forms-localization-using-visual-studio-13832), para una explicación un poco más detallada. Aunque es un post de 2015 y está en inglés, creo que es bastante válido aún. Saludos

Comment: - Mauricio Contreras, encontré un artículo y el código de ejemplo, en teoría debería funcionar pero correr el programa y al selecciona el idioma del listbox no genera error, simplemente no funciona, ¡tiene que ver que ese artículo es del 2014 y estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2017? código: https://github.com/JuanKRuiz/WinFormsLocalizationDemo: artículo: https://juank.io/c-aplicaciones-multilenguaje-globalizacion-localizacion/

Comment: Hola, pues habrá que ver qué sucede. La idea es que crees un simple `form`, le añadas al menos un elemento y hagas la prueba. Si no funciona habrá que ver el código que estás implementando.